# Does any shop at Lima airport (Jorge Chavez International Airport, LIM) sell SIM cards at a similar price as outside the airport?

Tags: cellphones, peru, tourist-traps, lima, lim

I read on https://travelingwithsunscreen.com/how-to-get-a-sim-card-in-lima-peru ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20191208000410/https://travelingwithsunscreen.com/how-to-get-a-sim-card-in-lima-peru/)) that one of the SIM card shops at Lima airport ([Jorge Chavez International Airport, LIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jorge_Ch%C3%A1vez_International_Airport)), namely the  Claro kiosk in the  baggage claim area, is only selling overpriced SIM card (~60 USD, vs. ~6 USD outside the airport):

> The sign on the kiosk indicated that a seven-day play cost $59 US dollars.

Does any shop at Lima airport (Jorge Chavez International Airport, LIM) sell SIM cards at a similar price as outside the airport?

I'm not trying to overoptimize the price, but simply trying to avoid tourist traps by not paying ~10 times more than one should.